# Deserializing XML @Element and @ElementList with same name from different XML datasets

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing, deserialization

I want to deserialize different sets of XML serialized data into one class (not at the same time) using [SimpleXML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php).

All of the datasets have a root class of `<body/>`, but different subclasses. Some have one element of `<prediction>`, other multiple elements of `<prediction>`. Same for `<route>`. This is the code I currently use, but it gives me an error of type `PersistenceException` ("Duplicate annotation").

What would be the simplest way to solve this? Any help would be appreciated.

```
@Root(name = "body", strict = false)
class NextBusAPIResult {
    @Attribute(name = "copyright")
    public String Copyright;

    @Element(name = "predictions", required = false, type = Predictions.class)
    public Predictions Predictions;

    @ElementList(name = "predictions", required = false, inline = true)
    public List<Predictions> PredictionsForMultiStops;

    @Element(name = "route", required = false, type = RouteInfo.class)
    public RouteInfo RouteInfo;

    @ElementList(name = "route", required = false, inline = true)
    public List<RouteSchedule> RouteSchedules;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to solve this is to use multiple elements always. Just remove code related to single elements.